# Optimal git workflow/strategy for pull requests to open source projects

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge, git-rebase

I am looking for clear, simple and optimal strategy for working on a public project, which includes:

1. pulling recent changes
2. adding my work on top of the history
3. submitting pull request for review with clean history

By *optimal* I mean a minimum number of steps, and most importantly -

**Maximal automation and minimal chance to create a conflict**.

---

In my setup I am working on my local `dev` branch. Say I decide it is ready for a pull request. What are my steps and what are rules to follow to stay out of troubles?

1. I first need to make sure my most recent `commits` are on top of the current history. So I need to `rebase` my new commits on top of the most recent public changes. I don't want to `merge` to avoid additional `merge commit`, which is of no public interest:

   git rebase origin/master dev
2. Now my new `commit` history is clean and sits on top of the most recent public `master` branch. I can't `push` it directly to the public `origin` as I don't have write access. Instead I push it to my **forked remote repository** on Github. But here is the question:

*To which remote branch should I push it?*

The problem is the **clean history** - I want that remote branch to be exactly identical with my local `dev`. So the best candidate seems to be a **new feature branch** cloned from `origin/master`:

*Any simple way of doing it on Github?*

3. Now I have exact copy of `origin/master` in my forked repo as my new branch say `new-feature-x`. I need to update it to become exact copy of my local `dev` branch:

*What would be the simplest and most reliable way to do it?*

4. So hopefully now I have branch `new-feature-x` on my forked repo that I can submit for a pull request to `origin` repo. Assuming (and hoping) there won't be any conflicts, that step is easy.

So that would have a perfect strategy if having good answers to the above questions.

Any help is appreciated!

---

EDIT.

Many sources refer to [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). However, this doesn't seem suitable for public projects with many collaborators. The public project may not even have a `development` branch or anything similar. And having such a branch on my local repo indefinitely could be a pain to update it with whatever pull requests are accepted/amended/rejected and so on.

Further, this model suggests keeping all merge records. But my internal merges are of no use to public, only adding unnecessary overhead. As mentioned above, I want to make a Pull Request with **clean history** to make the *job of maintainers as easy as possible*.

---

I have found the following command extremely useful before any `push`:

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

Here I am using [remote](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) called "upstream" for the public repo (and "origin" for my own fork).

This command will pull the current state of the public repo's master branch and sync it with my local *feature branch* that I am about to submit for pull request. If there are any conflicts, I can see and resolve them all at this stage - conveniently on my local machine.

Having done that, there is much less chance to get conflicts when making the actual pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've forked, you should immediately `git checkout -b feature-branch` (with an appropriate descriptive name for `feature-branch` of course). Once you've added some commits locally, you perform `git push -u origin feature-branch` to create that branch on your remote fork. Future pushes in that branch do not require those parameters.

Once you've completed your work, then you just issue the pull request **to whichever branch the project specifies.** That may be `master` or `dev` or something else, depending on the guidelines.

I'd caution against using `git rebase` too much, though, because if someone else has pulled the same branch, then you rebase and `git push -f` then suddenly you have two different histories and bad things can happen.

Additional reading:

- [Fork a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)
- [Using pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/)
- [Git flow branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (Not necessarily GitHub specific)

Comment: Many thanks! `-u` is useful! But I think I need to `rebase` before `push`. Otherwise I end up with pull request having merge conflicts, that I rather resolve locally. I am only using `rebase` locally - are there any concerns here?

Comment: If you `rebase` before pushing upstream, and you don't have any other collaborators on your fork, them it will probably be fine.